# I need to implement a working method using string interpolation

Tags: ruby, string, rspec

I have the following method:

```
def add(a,b)
  a + " + " + b + " = " + (a + b)
end
```

The following RSpec test is in play:

```
describe "add" do
  it "returns a string with 1 and 2 added" do
    expect( add(1,2) ).to eq("1 + 2 = 3")
  end
  it "returns a string with 5 and 7 added" do
    expect( add(5,7) ).to eq("5 + 7 = 12")
  end
end
```

I am getting the following error:

> String can't be coerced into Fixnum exercise.rb:2:in `+'
>
> exercise.rb:2:in `add'
>
> exercise_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in '

I tried the following without a passing test as well:

```
"#{a}" + " + " + "#{b}" + " = " + (a + b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `a`, `b`, `a + b` all into the string interpolation:

```
def add(a,b)
  "#{a} + #{b} = #{a + b}"
end
add(1, 2)
# => "1 + 2 = 3"
```

---

The error is thrown because the code is trying to concatenate string and number:

```
>> " " + 2
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
        from (irb):1:in `+'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

If you want to do it, you need to convert the number to string before the concatenation:

```
>> " " + (2).to_s
=> " 2"
```

Comment: I think the coercion error is coming from `1 + " + "`

Comment: @Anand, I answered according to the last code snippet in the question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was referring to the original error in the question `String can't be coerced into Fixnum`.

Comment: @Anand Thanks a bunch mate!! It's been a while since being back in n00bieville. :D